# How to list all groups in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am using this command "gcloud identity groups search" (with --page-token set) and python api to get all groups in GCP, in the console I go to groups and see there are around 2000 groups, but the command and API isn't giving all the groups. Was wondering if this is the right way to get the groups in GCP..

Comment: What is the output when you ran the command `gcloud identity groups search` ? Or how many were listed?

Comment: This is working fine, all I need to do is set the project..

Comment: how you set the page-token?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get all the groups using the following command:

```
gcloud identity groups search --labels="cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum" --organization="<org_id>" --page-size=3000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).